# Magento defining custom CMS page in cms.xml

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system

I added several pages (cms) in my Magento admin panel. I know I can attach blocks to a specific page by using {{block..}} within the content field.

I do not want to define blocks there, but within the cms.xml file. So other store admins are not annoyed by weird codes ({{block..}}) in the backend editor.

I defined the index/home page with the following xml tag:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block... />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

How can I define other cms pages (by id or seo-identifier) within cms.xml?

I tried defining them by;

```
<cms_page_[seo-ident]>
<cms_pageid_[id]>
<cms_[seo-ident]>
<cms_[id]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow Alan Storm is not familiar with CMS module, it is surely a very old thread.

It's on the top list when I Google-ed it though

Matthias Zeis provide a nice answer for this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289/cms-xml-handles-for-layout-updates

Basically the idea is to observe event `cms_page_render` and then we define our own handle.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not super familiar with the CMS module, but I can tell you how to get the XML tag/handle (cms_index_index) for any page in your system.

- Download and install the [LayoutViewer Module](http://alanstorm.com/2005/projects/MagentoLayoutViewer.tar.gz) from [this tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) (reading the tutorial is probably a good idea too)
- Load your CMS page with the added query string `showLayout=handles`

  http://example.com/helloworld/index/index?showLayout=handles

You should now see a list of "handles".  Handles are used to identify particular requests. For example cms_index_index is the handle that identifies a request for the **CMS** module's **index** action on the its **index** controller. You should see similar handles on your other CMS pages.

If this works post a follow up in the comments, I'm curious how the CMS handles are formed and haven't had time to search it out.

**Update**: I've done this on a testbed install of Magento that I have kicking around.  I created a simple CMS page available at the following URL

```
http://example.com/index.php/this-is-my-identifier
```

And I got the following handles

1. default
2. cms_page
3. STORE_default
4. THEME_frontend_default_default
5. cms_page_view
6. page_one_column
7. customer_logged_out

So, based on this, it looks like Magento doesn't create an individual handle for each CMS page (I'm kind of surprised the cms_index_index you mentioned above works ... which  means there's probably something going on I don't quite understand).

So, what I'd try to do is define your blocks within a `<cms_page>` or `<cms_page_view>` tag.  That should make them available to **all** your CMS pages.

Comment: Would you care to update this answer or is it no longer worth it? I would be interested to see what you have learned on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Magento is not so easy to handle in terms of the layouts. You can check [this blog entry](http://www.geekieblog.com/2011/04/creating-a-new-layout-for-specific-cms-pages-in-magento/) of my own, even when it doesn't explain about blocks specifically I think it might help you understand how the custom layouts work with CMS pages.

Once from there, you might get a clearer idea of the process.

I hope it helps.